# Uninitialized local variable in switch

Tags: c++

I have a very simple switch case menu, however i get this error: 
uninitialized local variable 'userInput' used

```
int main(void) {
char userInput;
while (userInput != 'q')
{
  cin >> userInput;

  switch (userInput)
  {
    case 'a': break;
    default: break;
  }// end switch
}//end while
return 0;
}//end main
```

I made this in ubuntu and it worked fine, i tried it in visual studio on windows it gives me the error. Any help is appreciated because it looks fine to me.

Comment: It should be at least a warning on both.

Comment: If it looks fine then you haven't bothered to look at all... Read the error. Look at lines 2 and 3.

Comment: Hint: What is of the value of userInput before the `while (userInput != 'q')` ?

Comment: Ok, i see it now, weird that it worked under netbeans

Comment: It must have a very bad default compiler settings or someone changed the settings to bad value (ignoring this type of warning).

Comment: It's not an error, unless you have some funky compiler setting that treats warnings as errors.

Comment: You were lucky enough to get a compiler error message that was actually clear and unambiguous, and you're complaining about it?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error; it's a *warning*, and one that you did not turn on when you tested on Ubuntu (though you should have done).

The reason for its emission is exactly what it says: you did not initialise `charInput` when you declared it. Immediately afterwards, you compare it to `'q'` — how can you compare an uninitialised value to `'q'`? You're just begging for surprises.

Answer (score 0):

you should always initialize your variables before using them and you should read the errors and google them before asking them in here

```
int main(void) {
    char userInput;
    cin >> userInput;
    while (userInput != 'q')
    {
      switch (userInput)
      {
        case 'a': break;
        default: break;
    cin >> userInput;
      }// end switch
    }//end while
    return 0;

}//end main
```